# Busy Indicator is not working?

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

My Xaml code:

```
<telerik:RadBusyIndicator Name="RadBusyIndicator" IsBusy="True"
                          Margin="34,32,58,36" Visibility="Collapsed"
                          Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="2">
</telerik:RadBusyIndicator>
```

And i have the button name called "Import" on click of the Import button making the busy indicator as

```
RadBusyIndicator.visibility=visibility.visible;
```

the Busy indicator is not visible is my code is wrong?

Comment: what do you mean its not working?

Comment: The busy indicator is not at all visible

Comment: The busy indicator should be the ROOT of your window/control/whatevs.  All other controls go INSIDE.   `<t:RadBusyIndicator><Grid><etc>`  When `Busy="true"` the indicator shows an overlay that sits on top of all child controls.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set its IsBusy to true.
Also are you running your code on background thread.

Busy indicator should contain controls that will get disabled when its IsBusy is true. Usually make the whole window content of BusyWindow.

```
<telerik:RadBusyIndicator Name="RadBusyIndicator" IsBusy="True" Margin="34,32,58,36" Grid.RowSpan="4" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2">

<Button Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2" Content="Import" Width="120" Height="30" IsEnabled="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="btnImport" Click="btnImport_Click" Margin="76,5,79,5"></Button> 

</telerik:RadBusyIndicator>
```

Comment: If you are asking for clarification of details you should post it as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: <Button Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2" Content="Import" Width="120" Height="30" IsEnabled="False"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="btnImport" Click="btnImport_Click" Margin="76,5,79,5"></Button>
                    <telerik:RadBusyIndicator Name="RadBusyIndicator" IsBusy="True" Margin="34,32,58,36" Grid.RowSpan="4" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"></telerik:RadBusyIndicator>

Comment: private void btnImport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
     
            RadBusyIndicator.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
           RadBusyIndicator.IsBusy = true;

            string _blockcode = combBlock.SelectedValue.ToString();
            DataImportModel DIM = new DataImportModel();
            AuditLoginModel Audit = new AuditLoginModel();
            int TXN_Tables = 0;
            int TblEnrollCount = 0;

Comment: <Button Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2" Content="Import" Width="120" Height="30" IsEnabled="False"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="btnImport" Click="btnImport_Click" Margin="76,5,79,5"></Button>
                    <telerik:RadBusyIndicator Name="RadBusyIndicator" IsBusy="True" Margin="34,32,58,36" Grid.RowSpan="4" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"></telerik:RadBusyIndicator>

Comment: <Button Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2" Content="Import" Width="120" Height="30" IsEnabled="False"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="btnImport" Click="btnImport_Click" Margin="76,5,79,5"></Button>
                                      
                                                                                                                                         <telerik:RadBusyIndicator Name="RadBusyIndicator" IsBusy="True" Margin="34,32,58,36" Grid.RowSpan="4" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"></telerik:RadBusyIndicator>